# Challenge - How to stretch an object through a plane

Tags: modeling, effects

I would like to create this effect (white face image), but with a map (country map).
As if my map where pushed from behind a white grainy plastic film.
I searched some tutorial on Youtube, but could't fine any solution.

Does this effect have a specific name that I could search for ?
I saw a lot of "cloth simulation" or "vacuum situation" but I don't want any fold in the result.

Does someone know how to achieve this ?

I appreciate your help. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could try using the shrinkwrap modifier on the white plane instead of cloth

Comment: Hi Nascent, thank you very much for your help. That what I tried first without success.
I currently have 1 place (The base).
A second plane (The map, created thanks to simple subdivision and displacement)
A Cube, that I Shrink-wrap around the two planes.
Without success so far. I continue my search :)
Thank you for taking time to answer me. Claire

Comment: "Without success" Could you expand on that? Adding some more images to your question and pointing out what needs to be different would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Something like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUfUG.png

Comment: Hi Hiserod, yes exactly what is in your image ! How did you succeed ?
I tried Warp, Schrinkwrap, but I couldn't do what you achieved.
Would you share with me what step you followed ?
Thanks, Claire